# Unable to export/import a TypeScript class: "TypeError: Messenger is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript2.0

I have a class implemented in a Typescript file, and I am able to successfully create a new object in the same file it is implemented, but if I try to export/import them in separate files I am hitting issues. See error message below:

ERROR

```
nodemon] starting `ts-node src/TestBot.ts`
Initializing Messenger

/Users/some_user/Documents/Src/some_folder/src/TestBot.ts:14
let myBot =  new Messenger(my_page_access_token, my_page_verify_token);
                ^
TypeError: Messenger is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous (/Users/some_user/Documents/Src/some_folder/src/TestBot.ts:14:17)
```

I would appreciate any pointers to fix the issue.

This is the main file where the Messenger class is implemented

```
// index.ts
class Messenger extends events.EventEmitter {
    private readonly pageAccessToken: String;
    private readonly pageVerifyToken: String;

    constructor(pageAccessToken: String, pageVerifyToken: String) {
        super();
        if (!pageAccessToken || !pageVerifyToken) {
            console.error("Missing Messenger Tokens");
            throw new TypeError("Missing Messenger Tokens");    
        }
        console.log("Initializing Messenger");
        this.pageAccessToken = pageAccessToken;
        this.pageVerifyToken = pageVerifyToken;
    }
...
...
}
...
export = Messenger;
```

In a TestBot.ts file in the same directory I am instantiating it

```
// TestBot.ts
import Messenger = require('./index');

let http = require('http');

let my_page_access_token = 'access_token';
let my_page_verify_token = 'verify_token';

let myBot =  new Messenger(my_page_access_token, my_page_verify_token);
```

EDIT1:

Various permutations tried

I have tried various permutations of

```
// index.ts
// export = Messenger;
// module.exports = Messenger;
// export default Messenger;
// export * from './index';
// export {Messenger};
// export default Messenger;


// TestBot.ts
// import { Messenger } from './index';
// import Messenger from './index';
// import Messenger = require('./index');
// import './index.ts'
```

Comment: are yo using ES6 imports in node from TS?

Comment: Which command are you using ti compile the .TS files? with --out option?

Comment: @Niladri --> ts-node src/TestBot.ts and target is "ES5" as per tsconfig.json

// nodemon.json
{
  "verbose": false,
  "watch": ["src/*.ts"],
  "ext": "ts",
  "ignore": ["node_modules"],
  "exec": "ts-node src/TestBot.ts"  
}

Comment: can you try with the `import {Messenger} from './index'`. sometimes it's due to the circular dependency in node due to `require` as it returns `{}`

Comment: no i am asking about importing in your testbot.ts file. Which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: @Niladri typescript@2.5.2

Yes, I am importing them in TestBot.ts ( the formatting is messed up in comments, so I added an Edit1)

Comment: Where do you actually import `events`? don't see that.

Comment: @James At the top of index.ts; I only included the code relevant for the question. Infact,  if i paste TestBot.ts inside index.ts, my code works fine. I am having issue with export/import of the user defined class "Messnger"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the name of file with the class definition can not be "index.ts". After, changing it to some other name, I am no longer having issues.

I will update with more details if I can find the exact reason. Also, happy to hear explanations from others.